# Toggle JavaScript function when entering rest webservices URL

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have two forms in the same page and one appears when clicking on the icon the login disappear and the signup appear.  I am using spring mvc so I want when entering /register the function which toggle the forms work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Login Form</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
          href="../static/css/reset.css"/>

    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch'
          href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900|RobotoDraft:400,100,300,500,700,900'/>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css"/>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"
          href="../static/css/style.css"/>


</head>

<body>


<!-- Mixins-->
<!-- Pen Title-->

<div class="container">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card">
        <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
        <form action="login" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${login}" method="post" >
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="email" id="email" th:field="*{email}"  required="required"/>
                <label for="email">email</label>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="password" id="Password" th:field="*{password}"  required="required"/>
                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container">
                <button  type="submit" name="action" value="login"><span>Go</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="footer"><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="card alt">
        <div class="toggle"></div>
        <h1 class="title">Register
            <div class="close"></div>
        </h1>
        <form action="register" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${register}" method="post">
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="text" id="firstName" th:field="*{firstName}" required="required"/>
                <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="text" id="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}" required="required"/>
                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="email" id="email_" th:field="*{email}" required="required"/>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <input type="password" id="Password_" th:field="*{password}" required="required"/>
                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container">
                <button  type="submit" name="action" value="register"><span>Next</span></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script th:src="@{/js/index.js}"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code :

```
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.container').stop().addClass('active');
});

$('.close').on('click', function() {
  $('.container').stop().removeClass('active');
});
```

i want for example when entering /register it retrieve the register form instead of login

Comment: An example project on GitHub would help us understand the problem.

Comment: ok ,I have add the code in the question :)

Comment: I see two forms that use different action endpoints.  Login Form uses "/login" endpoint.  Register Form uses "/register" endpoint.  This should work just fine.  What specific problem are you having? A full example on GitHub is what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to create a **/register** controller that will return a parameter:

```
@RequestMapping("/register") 
public ModelAndView register() {
   ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("your_form_page")
   mv.addObject("isRegister", true);
   return mv;
}
```

Then you can add a hidden field and use it in the javascript to toggle the divs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <head>
        <!-- imports omitted -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                if ($("#isRegister").val()) {
                    $("#register").show();
                    $("#signUp").hide();
                } else {
                    $("#register").hide();
                    $("#signUp").show();
                }
            });
        </script>


    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="isRegister" type="hidden" th:value="${isRegister}" disabled="disabled"/>


        <div id="signUp">
            Sign Up Form
        </div>
        <div id="register">
            Register Form
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Of course you can move the Javascript piece of code to your ".js" file. The important here is to have the hidden input field that will be accessible in the Javascript to toggle the DIVs.